# How to change the default network socket timeout in DCMTK?

Tags: swift, dicom, dcmtk

The default network socket timeout in DCMTK is 60 seconds.

How to change it to 30?

I could see the code written as below, but could not change it to 30:

```
extern DCMTK_DCMNET_EXPORT OFGlobal<Sint32> dcmSocketReceiveTimeout;   /* default: 60 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you want to set the timeout programmtically.
You can check how to do this in the dcmtk tools like [echoscu](https://github.com/DCMTK/dcmtk/blob/master/dcmnet/apps/echoscu.cc) -- basically you have to call:

```cpp
#include "dcmtk/dcmnet/dcmtrans.h"

dcmSocketReceiveTimeout.set(OFstatic_cast(Sint32, new_socket_timeout));
```

and the global timeout will change accordingly.
The same is true for setting the send timeout, where you use `dcmSocketSendTimeout` instead.